# Parabolic/Elliptic equation with nonlinear gradient term

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde

Let $a\in (0,1)$ and $(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, we consider the below equation in $(0,1) \times (0,T)$
$$ \partial_t u -\partial_x^2 u - \dfrac{1}{|u|^a} \partial_x u =f(x).$$
And $u(x,0)=x^{1/a}$ and $u(0,t)=0$.

Does anyone have some articles concerning this kind of equation? Or its elliptic version? What keyword should I search for?